# What's the universal standard to get data from any blog?

Tags: rss, xml-rpc, atom-feed

I want to extract data from various kinds of blogs and was going through various ways to do it:

> 1. API which needs user authentication
> 2. XML RPC(Don't know which all support it)
> 3. RSS(Again, not sure which blogs support it and even if they do, how much can one get from RSS feeds.)
> 4. Atom

I know that this isn't a strictly programming related question but I went forward in asking this as there is heck lot of confusion as to what to use and which is better served?

It would be nice to not use API with Authentication as you not only will have to tackle with varied implementations of Authentication, you also have to deal with varied API limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSS is the oldest that came into use. There are limitations to it. Atom was designed to be the replacement for it, overcoming the limitations of RSS. Atom is just a specialised form of XML RPC. In other words, there are other uses for XML RPC, and Atom is the variation of it you want. All of the above are a type of API. So ideally what you want to do is support RSS and Atom. Sadly Atom and RSS are not backwards compatible. To quote the [Wikipedia on "Atom"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29):

> In particular, many blog and wiki sites offer their web feeds in the
>   Atom format.

@porneL's solution is not recommended (at the moment). However in the future, HTML markup is set to change to improve the semantic meaning given to blocks, such as the new `<article>` tag. This will be yet another way to parse documents. It will be the most versatile, but in my opinion it will be a very long time before it becomes reliable, since many if not most sites suffer from 'tag soup' syndrome.

Comment: So you're saying that if I've to get all the data from a blog, Atom/RSS should do? What if a blog doesn't support RSS or supports it partially. Then?

Comment: Your code should do what it can to test what a blog supports. First test Atom since it's most versatile. Otherwise test RSS. For each you'll also need to test the different fields to see if they're blank. It may help to have a read thought official specs for Atom and RSS to see what the standard implementation would be. Be aware of course that some blogs may not be coded correctly. However, if you just want the title, body and timestamp hopefully you won't have too many problems.

Answer (score 1):

The most *universal* "standard" is crawling and parsing HTML.

```
wget -m http://example.com/
```

How exactly you do it depends on what are you trying to accomplish and how universal you want to be.

You could use heuristics, similar to what Readability uses, to find articles on a site. You could detect and special-case popular blogging platforms.

Comment: I generally crawl most sites. But it is painful as there might be data loss while cleaning up the data. Readablity is pretty much my exact usecase. But they are crawling just one page. What happens if you are supposed to crawl the complete archive? Won't an API based solution be better?

Comment: Yes, API will definitely be higher-fidelity, but there's no single API that works across all sites.